# Using Perl regex to find and extract matches over multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file of several hundreds of terms in the following format:

```
[Term]  
id: id1  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aab  
xref: type2:cdc  

[Term]  
id: id2  
name: name2  
xref: type1:aba  
xref: type3:fee
```

I need to extract all terms with an xref of type1 and write them to a new file in the same format. I was planning to use a regular expression like this:

```
/\[Term\](.*)type1(.*)[^\[Term\]]/g
```

to find the corresponding terms but I don't know how to search for a regex over multiple lines. Should I read the original text file as a string or rather line for line?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you show your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach could be to use `$/` variable to split blocks in a blank line, for each block split it with a newline character and then run a regular expression for each line.So when one of them matches print and read next block. An example with a one-liner:

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $/ = q|| }
    my @lines = split /\n/;  
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/xref:\s*type1/ ) {     
            printf qq|%s|, $_;
            last;
        }
    }
' infile
```

Assuming an input file like:

```
[Term]
id: id1
name: name1
xref: type1:aab
xref: type2:cdc

[Term]
id: id2
name: name1
xref: type6:aba
xref: type3:fee

[Term]
id: id2
name: name1
xref: type1:aba
xref: type3:fee

[Term]
id: id2
name: name1
xref: type4:aba
xref: type3:fee

[Term]  
id: id2  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aba  
xref: type3:fee
```

It yields:

```
[Term]  
id: id1  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aab  
xref: type2:cdc  

[Term]  
id: id2  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aba  
xref: type3:fee 

[Term]  
id: id2  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aba  
xref: type3:fee
```

As you can see, only those with a line `xref: type1` in them are printed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for me! Now I just have to try and understand the code...

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex :

```
/(?s)\[Term\].*?xref: type1.*?(?=\[Term\])/g
```

This regex has the following notable changes:

- `(?s)` turns on "dot matches newline"
- `.*?` is a *non greedy* expression. Using `.*` will consume everything to the last `[Term]` in the file
- removed unnecessary grouping around `.*?`
- Added slight refinement to match *xref*, not just type1 anywhere
- removed incorrect syntax for following Term marker
- Added a look -ahead to match up to, but not including, the next `[Term]` marker

Comment: I tried this:
     while (<MYFILE>) {
     $string = <MYFILE>;
     @matches = $string =~ (?s)\[Term\](.*?)type1(.*?)(?=\[Term\])/g;
     }
     close (MYFILE);
 
 but it didn't work yet and returned 
     "Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/s) <-- HERE \[Term\](.*/"

Comment: Are there backslashes before all square brackets? (They aren't showing in your comment. Surround code in comments with back ticks to show as code font)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations of the new regex. I tried `while (<MYFILE>) {
 /(?s)\[Term\].*?xref: type1.*?(?=\[Term\])/g and print;
 }
 close (MYFILE);` but there is still no output. Should I read the file as a string or line for line?

Comment: You would have to read it a one single input for this to work - as a "string".